# Is it possible to create anchors in the numbers of an <ol> list?

Tags: html, css

I need a clarification regarding the link creation for `<ol>` list in the HTML page.

Here is the example code for reference.

```
<ol>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ol>
```

that gives this as output:

1. test
2. test

I need to create the links only on the numbers preceding the actual text. Is it possible?

Comment: You could look into custom list-style-type hacks. Those usually require setting the `content` property on the `li:before` pseduo-element, and I'd bet a lot of ereaders don't support that. For what you are trying to do, it would probably be easier to build out your list manually with `<div>`s and `<p>`s instead of using the list element. Then the numbers would be actual text which you could wrap with an anchor tag.

Answer (score 2):

Earlier in text:

```
<a name="header1">Header 1</a>

<a name="header2">Header 2</a>

further down...

<ol>
<li><a href="#header1">item one</a></li>
<li><a href="#header2">item two</a></li>
</ol>
```

If you're making an EPUB book, every tag must be closed, or self-closed. 
idiotprogrammer had the syntax right, but the example did not work (for IDPF specs).

```
<img src="image1.jpg" id="image0001" title="this is self-closed" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your example doesn't pass epubcheck. Also you can't use **name** as an attribute, you'll have to use **id**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which does what you need:

```
<ol>
<a href="#"><li></li></a> 
<a href="#"><li></li></a>
</ol>
```

(I tried putting a non-breaking space there, but it underlined the space. You could probably use css to set **text-decoration: none** for the **a** element.)

If you want the links to go anywhere, you could replace "#" with an anchor URL.

**Update:** Ahh, I see that the content model doesn't allow A tag underneath OL. So my answer is wrong.

Comment: That's fine, fortunately, the IDPF standard will not accept the below code while validate the HTML page.

Comment: This is very interesting. Any idea what the validation error is? I guess you're validating against HTML 5, so it may be stricter about empty elements.or bad href references...